# Using Identity Models vs Custom Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, authorization, asp.net-identity

So I need to add user authentication to a web application I'm building - Web Forms, not MVC - and have been trying to read up on the Microsoft provided/developed Identity models with user and either roles or claims - I prefer roles, but it looks like MS wants everyone to switch to claims. While I understand it has built in capability, I was wondering if it is just simpler to salt & hash a password, give users a software-defined "role" and test the user's role when loading pages. Or should I really try to do it the Microsoft way? Perhaps I just don't understand MS's framework well enough to implement.

---

**A few questions:**

1. Where are the users, roles etc stored? I believe these are placed in a custom generated database, but where?
2. Is this database easily moved to a production database?
3. How can I edit the roles to make them specific to my application? Apparently, MS has done away with the configuration tool that made this process easier. I can download an older version of Visual Studio to access the tool, but that seems rather cumbersome.
4. The big one. I'm guessing that if I create my own self contained integrated authorization system I would not be able to use webconfig to authorize access?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found that #1 is stored locally in a SQL db.

Answer (score 0):

1. Places where your users/roles/claims are stored is configurable. Default Entity Framework implementation is storing data in SQL database. If you run it locally, with default template it'll create LocalDB database. You can configure it to use your existing SQL Server database.
   There are projects that allow you to save this data in RavenDb, MongoDb, AzureTables, MySql; I even seen discussion to have web.config as a definition of single admin user.
2. Yes. Deployed to production same way you deploy your regular DB.
3. MS have disposed of that tool you are talking about. Even if you download it, it will not work with the new way. Your options would be to either write role management yourself, go directly into DB and create roles there (if it is one-off job). Or use [Brock Allen's IdentityManager](http://brockallen.com/2014/04/09/introducing-thinktecture-identitymanager/) tool (beware though, this is not embeddable into other applications yet).
4. In Identity Framework you don't use web.config to configure anything. Apart from connection string. You can build your own implementation of `UserManager` that will take configuration parameters from `web.config`.

Regarding roles vs. claims. In Identity framework roles are a type of claim. Don't get caught on it too much, it is just different names for similar things. I highly recommend learning the "MS-way" and get Identity working (you don't have to use claims if you don't need them, roles will work just as they used to) and forget about MembershipProvider as nightmarish-legacy.